# How to apply an ApiFilter(SearchFilter: class) to a dynamic getter of an entity? [doctrine-orm, api-platform, graphql]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, graphql, api-platform.com

I'm new to php, doctrine and symfony. Please feel free to give me suggestions for improvement. Sry if my English isn't accurate.

### What do I want to achieve?

I want to:

- filter a collection (`Protocols`) by a **dynamic getter** (`getTimeTrackerState`) of my (`Protocol`) Entity model.
- see the filter in the graphql playground within the collection `protocols`.
- be able to execute a query with a filter value.

### My initial situation

**The Entity Code:** `Protocol.php`

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\DateFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProtocolRepository::class)
 * 
 * @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"dueDate"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"timeTrackerState": "exact", "state": "exact"})
 *
 */
class Protocol
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     *
     * @Assert\Uuid()
     */
    private $id;
    
    // some other fields
    
    // /**
    //  * @var string
    //  * 
    //  * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    //  */
    // public $timeTrackerState;
    
    public function getTimeTrackerState(): string
    {
        if ($this->getDaysUntilExeeded() <= 0) {
            return Protocol::TIME_TRACKER_EXEEDED;
        } elseif ($this->getDaysUntilUpcoming() <= 0) {
            return Protocol::TIME_TRACKER_UPCOMING;
        } else {
            return Protocol::TIME_TRACKER_NOT_UPCOMING;
        }
    }
    
    // not setter!
}
```

**graphql query:**

```
query GetProtocols {
  protocols(timeTrackerState: "UPCOMING") {
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
    }
    totalCount
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        ...ProtocolCore
        state
        timeTrackerState
        
        ... other stuff
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**loaded graphql schema docs (playground):**

[image: endpoint with timeTrackerState ApiFilter]

### What is the problem?

The filter is not available in graphql (see *loaded graphql schema docs*), as long as there is no field declared, which is annotated with (`@ORM\Column(type="string")`). If I declare this field named `timeTrackerState` , then this field appears in the *loaded graphql schema docs*, **but** I also need to store it in the database, what isn't what I want. Queries with a applied filter value (i.e. `timeTrackerState: "UPCOMING"`) will verify against the database and not against the dynamic getter `getTimeTrackerState()` of my entity class. I think this behaviour is intended of doctrine.

**Maybe I'm missing some basic functionality, or I'm completely off with my plan and should reconsider the structure.**

*I also thought about filtering it in the frontend, but then I need to fetch many unnecessary entries (`protocol`) with states I'm not interested in.*

### What I tried so far

- As described above, I used a `@ORM\Column(type="string")` field to write the field into the database and query it from there. The problem here is that I don't know how to keep it up to date.
- I wrote a [custom-resolver](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#custom-queries) which nearly does what I want, BUT then I end up having two queries for the same resource and they only differ in their arguments, which I want to have together.  I don't know how to merge my custom Resolver with the already provided Resolver used by `protocols`.

  - `ProtocolCollecctionResolver.php`:

    ```php
    use ApiPlatform\Core\GraphQl\Resolver\QueryCollectionResolverInterface;
    use App\Entity\Protocol;

    final class ProtocolCollectionResolver implements QueryCollectionResolverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @param iterable<Protocol> $collection
         *
         * @return iterable<Protocol>
         */
        public function __invoke(iterable $collection, array $context): iterable
        {
            ...
            return $collection    
        }
    ```
  - **usage of Resolver in Entity** `Protocol.php`:

    ```php
    /**
    * @ApiResource(
    *     graphql={
    *         "item_query",
    *         "collection_query",
    *         "delete",
    *         "update",
    *         "create",
    * 
    *         "collectionQuery"={
    *             "collection_query"=ProtocolCollectionResolver::class,
    *             "args"={
    *                 "timeTrackerState"={
    *                     "type"="String!",
    *                     "description"="The time state of the protocol"
    *                 }
    *             }
    *         },
    *     }
    * )
    * 
    * @Vich\Uploadable()
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProtocolRepository::class)
    * 
    * @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"dueDate"})
    * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"timeTrackerState": "exact", "state": "exact"})
    */
    class Protocol
    {}
    ```
  - **loaded graphql schema docs (playground):**

    [image: endpoint of extra resolver]

Thank you in advice!