# ApiPlatform/Symfony 6 - add searchfilter on custom getter (not in database)

Tags: php, database, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working on a project whit api platform 2.6 and symfony 6.

I have an Entity based on a table from my database.
My API exposes the fields of my table.

but I have a specific need to add information that does not exist in the database.
I create a custom getter, I integrated it into the normalization group, and it shows fine when responding from API.

But I would like to add a filter on this field.

```
ApiFilter(
    SearchFilter::class, properties: [
    'customInformation' => 'exact',
```

It does not work.

How to make Api-Platform take it into account as if it were a field of my database ?

Thank !
William

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [How to apply an ApiFilter(SearchFilter: class) to a dynamic getter of an entity? [doctrine-orm, api-platform, graphql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978118/how-to-apply-an-apifiltersearchfilter-class-to-a-dynamic-getter-of-an-entity)

ApiPlatform filters only work on properties for now.
You could probably accomplish that with a custom filter but i find it hard to imagine a case where you need to filter on data that does not exist.
There is probably a change on your conception that will do the job.

Update based on your comment :

I strongly advise you to change this

```
function getEmergency(): string 
{ 
   if ( $this->createdby == 'admin' and createdAt > days + 3) { 
     return 'urgent'; 
   }
   else 
   { 
     return 'not urgent';
   }
}
```

To something like this

```
function isUrgent(): bool 
{ 
   return  $this->createdby === 'admin' and createdAt > days + 3;
}
```

Much simplier method since there is only 2 case possible.

Then for your problem with api platform why dont you simply filter like this for example

`&createdBy=admin&createadAt[before]=20220105`

And inside your class

```
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['createdBy' => 'exact'])]
#[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['createdAt'])]
class foo {}
```

Look at this Syntax on the link bellow to better understand date filter with api platform: `?property[<after|before|strictly_after|strictly_before>]=value`

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#date-filter

Comment: I have a field createsAt and createdBy.  My custom getter is : public function getEmergency(): string { if ( $this->createdby == 'admin' and createsAt  > days + 3 { returm 'urgent' }else { return 'not urgent'}}

Comment: updated answer @guillaume
Dont hesite to edit your question instead of commenting only and i will provide better answer